# Rules of Unbounded type parameters in Generics ( C# )

Tags: c#, generics, null, constraints, nullable

I am unable to understand below points about unbounded type parameters.

> Type parameters that have no constraints, such as T in public class
> SampleClass{}, are called unbounded type parameters.
>
> Unbounded type parameters have the following rules: You can compare to
> null. If an unbounded parameter is compared to null, the comparison
> will always return false if the type argument is a value type.

I did not find any example of above points. It will be great if somebody give me example to understand the points.

Comment: What about it do you not understand?

Comment: Try it yourself `bool Test<T>(T val) => val == null;`.

Comment: FYI the technical reason, is that you are calling the `(object) == (object)` operator. Any value type will be boxed, which would always result in a non-null reference.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman if T=Int And Val=0 then return False ---___---- if T=String and Val="" then return false Too ............  Microsoft : the comparison will always return false if the type argument is a value type. sring is not value type

Comment: The generated IL is `ldarg.0, box !!T, ldnull, ceq`, the `box` operation will do nothing to an existing reference; https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABMugGxGoEDCBA3jgQ0YcWQEYD27EBAKgKYBnYOgA8PAHwAKHgQBuAQwgBKAgF5xcxWtUEAdgFcIEANw4AvkA= `null` is not exactly the same as `default(T)`. Unbound types don't have an `==` operator, so you have to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals()` to compare against `default(T)`. The caller gets to specify the type argument, and if the type argument is a value. eg `Test<int>(0);`

Comment: @Servy this" if the type argument is a value type. "  why is this condition placed if it shows the same behavior as the reference type?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank U it was answer of my question<3

Comment: @YaSecu Why do you think comparing a reference type to null is always false?

Comment: @Servy You opened my mind, i was in Dark
I understand, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these functions result in the same IL;

```cs
bool Test1<T>(T val) => val == null;
bool Test2<T>(T val) where T:class => val == null;

IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: box !!T
IL_0006: ldnull
IL_0007: ceq
IL_0009: ret
```

If the caller passes in a value type parameter;

```cs
Test1<int>(0) == false;
```

Then the integer argument will be boxed in an object, which will always result in a non-null reference. So comparing to `null` will always be false.

Though, if the caller passes in a `Nullable<T>` parameter. Even though this is a value type, [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-nullable%7Bt%7D#boxing-and-unboxing) the value will result in a `null`.

```cs
Test1<int?>(null) == true;
```

Boxing the value this way is an implementation detail, which might change in future versions. So the language reference you are quoting instead talks about the side effect of this implementation, rather than the cause.

For completeness, there's more that can be said about generic functions and equality.

Passing in an explicit `Nullable<T>` argument is also fine, and results in the same IL

```cs
bool Test3<T>(T? val) where T:struct => val == null;
bool Test4<T>(T? val) where T:struct => !val.HasValue;

IL_0000: ldarga.s val
IL_0002: call instance bool valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<!!T>::get_HasValue()
IL_0007: ldc.i4.0
IL_0008: ceq
IL_000a: ret
```

But there is no default `==` operator for value types;

```cs
bool Test5<T>(T val) where T:struct => val == null;
bool Test6<T>(T val) where T:struct => val == default(T);

error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and '<null>'
error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

Instead you can use the default comparer;

```cs
public bool Test7<T>(T val) => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(val, default(T));
```

Since .net 7 you can add a constraint which is implemented by .net numeric types;

```cs
public bool Test8<T>(T val) where T : IEqualityOperators<T,T,bool> => val == default(T);
```